# MySQL - How to find number of occurance in JSON?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-json

I have following table -

```
+-----+-----------+--------------------------------------+
| id  | client_id | service_values                       |
+-----+-----------+------------+-------------------------+
| 100 |      1000 | {"1": "60", "2": "64", "3": "92"}    |
| 101 |      1000 | {"1": "66", "2": "64", "3": "92"}    |
| 102 |      1000 | {"1": "70", "2": "64", "3": "92"}    |
| 103 |      1001 | {"1": "60", "2": "54", "3": "92"}    |
| 104 |      1001 | {"1": "90", "2": "64", "3": "92"}    |
| 105 |      1002 | {"1": "80", "2": "64", "3": "92"}    |
+-----+-----------+--------------------------------------+
```

I need to fetch **service_values** where 2 or more values is LESS THAN 65. For example from the above records, the expected result would be -

```
    +-----+-----------+--------------------------------------+
    | id  | client_id | service_values                       |
    +-----+-----------+------------+-------------------------+
    | 100 |      1000 | {"1": "60", "2": "64", "3": "92"}    |
    | 103 |      1001 | {"1": "60", "2": "54", "3": "92"}    |
    +-----+-----------+--------------------------------------+
```

I find a lot but couldn't find anything to perform aggregate function in JSON data.

**Update** - I tried something like this but couldn't succeed -

```
SELECT JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(service_values,'$.1')) AS A1, JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(service_values,'$.2')) AS A2, JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(service_values,'$.3')) AS A3 FROM service_data HAVING A1 < 65 OR A2 < 65 OR A3 < 65
```

Comment: What is **precise** MySQL version?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, I have "Server version: 10.4.14-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE (JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(service_values, "$.1")) < 65) 
     +(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(service_values, "$.2")) < 65) 
     +(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(service_values, "$.3")) < 65) >= 2;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=ea41cb428cbe356c9f98a99f59ca37dc